# Step Download Timeout in HP Load Runner 12.55

Tags: timeout, loadrunner

I am getting "Step download timeout (120 seconds) has expired when downloading resource" when running Load Runner (version 12.55) script for 300 concurrent users. This error occurs only for 1st, 101 and 201 vusers. Please help me on this strange issue. Is there any known issue in version 12.55?

Note:
I verified the corresponding resource download time and it is in seconds only. And I tried by increasing the download time in Runtime settings, but no luck.

Comment: Turn on think time

Comment: Think time is already Turned on and it is having "as recorded" option.